# Got CondaVerificationError when installing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, conda

I got a CondaVerificationError when installing Tensorflow on my 64-bit Win10.

```
CondaVerificationError: The package for tensorflow-estimator located at C:\Users\viviennejia.zhong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\tensorflow-estimator-1.13.0-py37h39e3cac_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear_optimizer/python/utils/__pycache__/sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
packages: conda-forge::tensorboard-1.13.1-py37_0, conda-forge::tensorflow-base-1.13.1-py37_7
path: 'scripts/tensorboard-script.py'

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
packages: conda-forge::tensorboard-1.13.1-py37_0, conda-forge::tensorflow-base-1.13.1-py37_7
path: 'scripts/tensorboard.exe'
```

In some posts I saw `conda clean --all` could help. Runing this, I got

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\tensorflow-base-2.0.0-mkl_py37hd1d5974_0\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow-2.0.0.data\\purelib\\tensorflow_core\\include\\tensorflow_core\\core\\common_runtime\\isolate_placer_inspection_required_ops_pass.h'
```

I am new to conda and appreciate very much your help to solve this issue.

Comment: Try this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Comment: @cactie, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the reference mentioned above ?

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors  I solved the problem by using pip to install tensorflow.

Answer (score 4):

You may be running into the path length limitation in Windows.

Setting `LongPathsEnabled` fixed it for me.

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later

Answer (score 1):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

Installation of Tensorflow through pip has resolved issue

```
pip install tensorflow (install latest version)
```

or

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0 (for older version)
```

In addition to above method, there is a recommended way is to create a `Virtual Environment` in `Anaconda` and install the `Tensorflow` in that `Virtual Environment`, which works in most of the cases.

Using Virtual Environments has advantages like

- We can maintain multiple versions of `Tensorflow` in multiple `Virtual Environments` with each `Virtual Environment` comprising each `version` like `1.14, 1.15, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2,etc..`
- We can use different `Python Versions` (`2.x, 3.6, 3.7`) in each `Virtual Environment`
- If we want to modify the `source code` of any of the Tensorflow API, we can do it within our Virtual Environment, without impacting its functionality in other `Virtual Environments`.

Steps for Creating a New Virtual Environment and installing `Tensorflow` in `Anaconda`, for different Operating Systems, is shown below:

```
# Create a New Virtual Environment
conda create --name TF_2_VE

# When conda asks you to proceed, type y:
proceed ([y]/n)?

# Activate the Virtual Environment. Conda Version > 4.6 
conda activate TF_2_VE

# Activating Virtual Environment, Conda Version < 4.6 and Windows OS
activate TF_2_VE

# Activating Virtual Environment, Conda Version < 4.6 and Linux and Mac OS
source activate TF_2_VE


# Install the TF Version you need
conda install tensorflow
```

The above command will install the `Latest Version` of `Tensorflow` (`2.2` as of now). If you want an older version like `2.0`, you can replace the last step of the above set of commands with

`conda install tensorflow==2.0`.