# Getting CondaVerificationError when installing tensorflow(windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I got error message when I am trying to setup tensorflow.

I examine a lot of discussion from github issues. I tried different versions but output doesn't change.

[image: Error message]

I saw this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918985/got-condaverificationerror-when-installing-tensorflow) in stackoverflow too but there is no answer avaliable.

I am trying to be more specific about error and platforms I am currently using and I hope someone help me or show me different approaches.

First of all I had python 3.6.x
but I deleted this version cause I want to make this setup clearly.

I downloaded **Anaconda** (Anaconda Python 3.7 version)

After that I checked my python version and its changed like 3.7 as I expected.

After that I follow the guide for setup **tensorflow**

```
conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
```

Because I want to use my gpu which is much faster comparing with CPU
(I already checked my gpu compability for tensorflow,I am currently using rtx 2060)

**Summary:**

-Anaconda Python 3.7 version

-Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem about insalling tensorflow maybe it will help other people.

Firstly, I just cleared my **PATH** under the **Environment Variable** which are related with Anaconda or you can delete Anaconda and reinstall.
After that open Anaconda command line and write:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```